# FormatException when trying to parse strings as floats

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to floats stored within a string.

```
Longitude   "15.628351800000019"    string
Latitude    "60.61594090000001" string
```

I am trying to parse these as floats like this

```
float.Parse(Longitude)
```

When i do that, FormatException i trowed. What could the problem be?
ASP.Net MVC 3 C#

Comment: Did you try to replace the `.` with `,`?

Comment: its not throwing exception, for latitude its showing 60.61594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
float lon = float.Parse(Longitude, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any);
```